# Create customized paths for HTML with flask

Tags: python, html, flask

is there a posibility to create an easy function like

```
def createPath(name):
    path = "abcd.jpg"
    finalPath = name + "/" + path
    return finalPath


(...)
path = createPath("folder1")
return render_template('index.html', PATH=path)
```

and use the returned *finalPath* in a html file like

```
<img src=" {{PATH}} " alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">
```

It does not work.

I don't know how to use variables in html.

Thank you a lot

Comment: Do you mean like url_for ? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/ 
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

By any chance, are you sure your url `name + "/" + path` is served by a web server ? If you want to serve static file you can have a look at https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/

This works for me :

```
from flask import Flask,render_template_string
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def hello_world():
    name = "flask-logo.png"
    path = createPath(name)

    return render_template_string("""<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head><title>Test</title></head>
        <body>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <img src="{{PATH}}" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">
        </body>
    </html>
""",PATH=path)

def createPath(name):
    path = "https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/_images"
    finalPath = path + "/" + name
    return finalPath


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: I forgot to create a folder named "static" and store the images there. After that I remove the " " around the curly brackets. Thanks for your advice.